# Change urls to lower case using UrlRewritingNet

Tags: c#, asp.net, seo, umbraco

i'm doing some work on a legacy asp.net and umbraco site. It's using UrlRewritingNet to set up rules for url manipulation.

I'd like to create a rule in the UrlRewritingNet file to convert all urls to lower case. Can you please help.

Comment: There is a similar question here that may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7523539/asp-net-url-rewrite-force-lowercase

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't appear to be a way to do this in the actual string in the config line. I think you can pretty easily write your own extension for this and just ToLower() the actual values when you process the rule.

http://www.urlrewriting.net/160/en/documentation/documentation/documentation/documentation/documentation.html